# jQuery accordion active state

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

## Navigation

```
<ul id="accordion">
  <li> 
    <a class="open_link"  href="#">1</a>
    <ul class="sub_accardion ">
      <li>
        <a class="sub_link"  href="#">1.1</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>    
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a class="sub_link"  href="#">1.2</a>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>    
          <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>    
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li> 
</ul>
```

---

## jQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript" >
$(function() {
    $( "#accordion" ).accordion({   
        header: '.open_link',       
        active: "false",
        heightStyle: "content",     
        collapsible: true, 
    }); 
    $( ".sub_accardion" ).accordion({   
        active:'false',
        header: '.sub_link',    
        heightStyle: "content",     
        collapsible: true, 
    });    
});
</script>
```

---

## Question

How can I add a class to set active on any panel?  I tried `active:'.active'`, but it doesn't work.

Comment: like http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UjT4p/1/

Comment: i got many pages, set new js every time is bad dessigion for me. I need set class in html or id.

Answer (score 1):

That is not the correct markup for the [jQuery UI Accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/).

Per their [documentation](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/):

> The underlying HTML markup is a series of headers (H3 tags) and
> content divs so the content is usable without JavaScript.

Since you are using **UL** tags, I think what you are looking for is the [jQuery UI Menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/#default).

Here is what I would do with your code:

---

## HTML

```html
<ul id="menu">
    <li> 
        <a class="open_link" href="#">1</a>
        <ul>
            <li> 
                <a class="sub_link" href="#">1.1</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.1.1</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li> 
                <a class="sub_link" href="#">1.2</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">1.2.1</a></li>
                </ul>   
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

---

## JQUERY

```js
$("#menu").menu();
```

---

## CSS

```css
.ui-menu { width: 100px; }
```

---

## ***[See working jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/yuZ7S/)***

Comment: $( ".selector" ).accordion({ active: 2 }); Dosent work for me i need class or id. Can u show me the whole js code ? I just cant understand where to set new active class.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do then?  Are you trying to default particular panels to be opened?  Including inside the sub panel?

Comment: For example i got 10 dif pages. In every i got opend a dif panel in menu. How can i set a active class for a panel and not to change the script in the head of the file every time. Sry for my bad english.

Comment: You do realize that you aren't using the correct markup right?  You are supposed to have h3 tags and divs for accordions.  Are you trying to do a [menu](http://jqueryui.com/menu/#default) instead?

Comment: yes i try to do navigation menu with this plagin. Is that what i want is possible ? or i just need use another plagin and dont waste time with this.

Comment: Yea, I think you are looking for the menu control.  Just take a look at my example http://jsfiddle.net/yuZ7S/ and you will see how it works. Very simple.

Comment: thanks for the answer @CodeMaverick..and suggesting the right markup for the question..

Comment: @Lucky - Yea, no problem!